# ListenWhisper doesn't receive an client event (Larave-echo & Vue.jsl)

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-echo

I'm working in a realtime chat website using `Laravel`, `laravel-echo`,`laravel-echo-server`, and `redis`. My chat is able to receive and send messages, but I want to add a message when a user start to typing ('User x is typing...'). But the client event is `typing` triggered

I have diferent `vue.js` components in this chat,

ChatApp.vue <- Main component

```
...
        mounted() {
            Echo.private(`message.${this.user.id}`)
            .listenForWhisper('.typing', (e) => { // This is listening for client event named typing
                console.log(e);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    console.log('works');
                }, 900);
            })
            Echo.private(`messages.${this.user.id}`) 
            .listen('.NewMessage', (e) => { //This is listening for a backend event named New Message
                this.handleIncoming(e.message);
                this.playSoundNotification();
            });
            axios.get('/user/contacts')
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data);
                this.contacts = response.data;
            });
        },
....
```

MessageComposer.vue component

```
<template>
    <div class="composer">
        <span @typing="typing_handler" v-show="typing" class="help-block" style="font-style: italic;">
            Tú amigo esta escribiendo...
        </span>
        <textarea v-model="message" @keydown="isTyping" @keydown.enter="send" placeholder="Message..."></textarea>
    </div>
</template>

<script >
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            message: '',
            typing:false,
        };

    },
    methods: {
        send(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if(this.message == ''){
                return;
            }

            this.$emit('send', this.message);
            this.message = '';
        },
        typing_handler(trigger){
            this.typing = trigger;
        },
        isTyping() {
            let  self_user_id = parseInt($('#self_user_id').val());
               var channel = Echo.private(`message.${self_user_id}`); //Client auth

                setTimeout(function() {
                    channel.whisper('typing', {

                        typing: true
                    });
                }, 300);

            },
    }
}
</script>
```

I don't get any error in my laravel-echo-server so I don't know what the problem is?
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes you may wish to broadcast an event to other connected clients without hitting your Laravel application at all. This can be particularly useful for things like "typing" notifications, where you want to alert users of your application that another user is typing a message on a given screen.

To broadcast client events, you may use Echo's whisper method:

```
Echo.private('chat')
    .whisper('typing', {
        name: this.user.name
    });
```

Comment: But I'm using whisper :/